# Is it possible to replicate SQL Server Express 2008 => SQL Server Express 2012?

Tags: sql-server, replication

Is it be possible to configure the one way replication between `SQL Server Express Edition 2008` => `SQL Server Express Edition 2012`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express (SQL Server Express) can serve as a Subscriber for all types of replication, providing a convenient way to distribute data to client applications that use SQL Server Express.
SQL Server Express cannot serve as a Publisher or Distributor.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165686(v=sql.105).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143699.aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc645993(SQL.110).aspx#Replication

Comment: thanks! the last link was that one I could not find.